# Trying to create a square in java but stars keep halving

Tags: java, loops, methods

new to a java course and have been trying to do this but struggling a bit. need to make a 6 by 6 square using to methods (previous one was to just make a row of 6 *).

any advice on where im going wrong would be amazing.

```
public class loopsLauncher {
    //Sterrenrij & SterrenVierKant
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //print * 8 times using a method and loop
        int aantal = 0;
        toonRijSterren(aantal);
        toonSterrenVierkant(aantal);
    }

    public static void toonRijSterren(int mpAantal) {
        while (mpAantal < 6) {
            System.out.print(" * ");
            mpAantal++;
        }
    }

    public static void toonSterrenVierkant(int mpAantal) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            ++mpAantal;
            System.out.println();
            toonRijSterren(mpAantal);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Int  `toonSterrenVierkan` you increment `++mpAantal`.  So each time thru you print one less star.  Comment out that line and try it.  And you don't need `toonRijSterren(aantal);` in main.

Comment: To elaborate on what @WJS said, within the for loop, i++ is already doing the incrementing. When you call `toonRijSterren(mpAantal)` its going to be starting at a higher number each time, thus your while loop will run less each time.

Comment: @primeld thanks very much for the explanation, works fine now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Dutch, so I put the names in English. Hope you'll understand.

If you want recursion, try the code below. The code will work for both rectangles and squares.

The first method (showRowStars) simply does a for-loop instead of the while loop you had that depended on mpAantal being 0.

For the second method (showRowsOfStars), it takes the number of rows as input. It calls the showRowStars method to print a row of stars and then it calls itself, except with one less row. When the number of rows (numRows) gets to 0, it stops.

If you don't want a rectangle, you can call the showStarSquare method which just calls the showRowsOfStars method but only needs one argument since both dimensions are the same.

```
public class loopsLauncher {
    //Sterrenrij & SterrenVierKant
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //print * 8 times using a method and loop
        showRowStars(6);
        showRowsOfStars(6, 6);
    }

    public static void showRowStars(int numStars) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numStars; i ++) {
            System.out.print(" * ");
        }
    }

    //numStars is stars per row
    public static void showRowsOfStars(int numRows, int numStars) {
        if (numRows == 0) return;
        showRowStars(numStars);
        showRowsOfStars(numRows - 1, numStars);
    }

    public static void showStarSquare(int numStars) {
      showRowsofStars(numStars, numStars);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use nested loops?

```
int sqSize = 6;
for (int i = 0; i < sqSize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sqSize; j++) {
        System.out.print(" *");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: It is probably a recursive exercise.

Comment: yeah its an exercise where they want me to use two methods for it